# How to install Windows android subsystem? (Amazon appstore)

Tags: android, windows, windows-11

I would like to install amazon appstore on my windows 11 but I see requirements error "This app can't work on your device" and link to CPU requirements [image]

But my CPU is satisfies requirements (i7-8750H).

Virtual Machine Platform feature also enabled.

How can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to your region. Here is the list of the regions Amazon Appstore is available:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/countries-and-regions-that-support-amazon-appstore-on-windows-d8dd17c7-5994-4187-9527-ddb076f9493e

You can get around this by setting your region to one of the ones listed above ^